# What javascript tools or techniques can I use to manage conflict resolution when multiple users are updating shared state within a Google Wave gadget?

Tags: javascript, google-wave, google-gadget

I think the answer to this question hinges on the whether or not it's possible to have access to the [Operational Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) architecture directly within the gadget API. It isn't currently there, so what might be the alternatives for fine-grained deltas, as opposed to just a big lock on each variable?

Comment: would love to see this one answered
have a look at http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/T_0115_Google_Wave_Under_the_Hood.pdf
you may consider using google-diff-match-patch/  http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Answer (score 1):

I think that the idea of Google Wave is that operational transformation is done and resolved on the server. So your gadget can only post delta's and get notified on updates, but could by definition not participate in conflict resolution and the like.

Interesting sideline could be how you could influence the way conflict resolution works be choosing a different form of storage from your gadget (dictionary with keys, arrays, strings). Some will behave differently in conflict situations, I'd expect.